# Svelte Derived Store atomic / debounced updates

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have been experimenting with svelte derived stores. If you look at the console log in the following example, after incrementing store 1 and store 2, then hitting reset, the derived store emits 2 updates.

How would you make this atomic or perhaps debounce it? For example, lets say the scenario were that the derived store issued a new network request based on the combined values of store 1 and 2, if they both changed together you wouldn't want to fire 2 network requsts?

https://svelte.dev/repl/a67c9d37aee348d988e8c30f60a139d9?version=3.28.0

EDIT: Actually, just added a 'reactive' console log and this appears to debounce (tick?) the output.

I think I have answered my own question?

Comment: Each reset changes a one store and therefore derived store updates two times. Yet the output value of derived store is updated only after the whole update loop has been run through as you found out with reactive log. One interesting thing is if you don’t have any (reactive?) reference to derived store in your component, the derived store won’t run or update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derived store's callback 2nd argument is `set`, which allows setting the derived value asynchronously.

```js
import { derived } from 'svelte/store';

const delayed = derived(a, ($a, set) => {
    setTimeout(() => set($a), 1000);
});

$: console.log($delayed);

$a = 1;
// console '1' 1 second later.
```

[API reference for `derived()`](https://svelte.dev/docs#derived)

---

For your case, you could call a debounce function that will eventually call `set`:

```js
// implementing debounce yourself
let timeoutId;
const total = derived([counter1, counter2], ([c1,c2], set) => {
    if (timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(c1, c2);
        return set(c1+c2);
    }, 1000);
}, 0);
```

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/600d5150bc414448bfce89a1152d8c84?version=3.28.0)

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto @TanLiHau's answer, you can also do this without the "global"/outer scope variable `timeoutId`.

Svelte's `derived` allows to return a callback for cleaning up (https://svelte.dev/docs#derived):

> If you return a function from the callback, it will be called when a) the callback runs again, or b) the last subscriber unsubscribes.

This allows you to write it as follows:

```js
const total = derived([counter1, counter2], ([c1,c2], set) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(c1, c2);
        return set(c1+c2);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
}, 0);
```