# Why does a derived Svelte store have different behaviour when using `$` vs `subscribe`

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, svelte-store

I have a data model that I can't change in this project. I'm trying to strip down and simplify the sample code below, so hopefully this still makes sense with what I'm trying to re-produce.

Let's say I have two stores. One store holds "containers" and the other store holds "items" - each store is independently used throughout the app for various purposes. The Container only holds Item IDs by default. Occasionally, I want to de-normalize the data for use on some pages. I use a derived store and denormalize each of the container objects, turning them into DenormalizedContainers.

Let's say I have a use case where I want to create a new Item object, and then add it to a given Container. As far as I can tell, that will cause the derived store to update twice (once for the change to items and again for a change to containers), and thus anything that uses that derived store will update twice (depending on how it's called).

Why would the behaviour be different from `subscribe` to `$`?

Also, while this isn't a huge problem for me, I'm just curious if there is any native Svelte-y way to workaround this without changing the data model (while still being able to use the `subscribe` API?

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { derived, writable } from "svelte/store";

    type Container = {
        id: string;
        itemIds: string[];
    };

    type Item = {
        id: string;
        name: string;
    };

    type DenormalizedContainer = {
        id: string;
        items: Item[];
    };

    const containers = writable<Container[]>([]);
    const items = writable<Item[]>([]);

    const denormalizedContainers = derived(
        [containers, items],
        ([$containers, $items]): DenormalizedContainer[] => {
            return $containers.map(({ id, itemIds }) => {
                const denormalizedContainer = {
                    id,
                    items: itemIds.map((id) =>
                        $items.find((item) => {
                            item.id === id;
                        })
                    ),
                };
                return denormalizedContainer;
            });
        }
    );

    function handleAddContainer() {
        const value = Math.random() * 1000;
        const newContainer: Container = { id: `new-container-${value}`, itemIds: [] };
        containers.set([...$containers, newContainer]);
    }
    function handleAddItem() {
        const value = Math.random() * 1000;
        const newItem: Item = { id: `new-id-${value}`, name: `new-name-${value}` };
        items.set([...$items, newItem]);
    }
    function handleAddBoth() {
        const value = Math.random() * 1000;
        const newItem: Item = { id: `new-id-${value}`, name: `new-name-${value}` };
        const newContainer: Container = { id: `new-container-${value}`, itemIds: [newItem.id] };
        items.set([...$items, newItem]);
        containers.set([...$containers, newContainer]);
    }

    $: console.log(`$: There are ${$containers.length} containers`);
    $: console.log(`$: There are ${$items.length} items`);
    $: console.log(`$: There are ${$denormalizedContainers.length} denormalized containers`);

    denormalizedContainers.subscribe((newValue) =>
        console.log(
            `Subscribe: There are ${$denormalizedContainers.length} denormalized containers`
        )
    );
</script>

<button class="block" on:click={() => handleAddContainer()}>Add container</button>
<button class="block" on:click={() => handleAddItem()}>Add item</button>
<button class="block" on:click={() => handleAddBoth()}>Add container and item</button>
```

### Results:

Upon clicking each button once, here are the logs:

Page load:

```
Subscribe: There are 0 denormalized containers
$: There are 0 containers
$: There are 0 items
$: There are 0 denormalized containers
```

Add container:

```
Subscribe: There are 1 denormalized containers
$: There are 1 containers
$: There are 1 denormalized containers
```

Add item:

```
Subscribe: There are 1 denormalized containers
$: There are 1 items
$: There are 1 denormalized containers
```

Add both:

```
Subscribe: There are 1 denormalized containers
Subscribe: There are 2 denormalized containers
$: There are 2 containers
$: There are 2 items
$: There are 2 denormalized containers
```

The updates handled via `$` are what I would like all the time, but for some reason the manual `subscribe` API shows two updates. I have a couple locations outside of `.svelte` files, where I would need to use the `subscribe` API.

### References:

Similar to this, but doesn't explain why the `$` behaves differently to the `subscribe`.

[Svelte Derived Store atomic / debounced updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087283/svelte-derived-store-atomic-debounced-updates)

Possibly the underlying problem?

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6730

Possibly explained in 3.1/3.2 here. Micro-tasks bundle up reactive statements and apply them at the end of the tick. Whereas `subscribe` handles updates in real-time. Note: Wrapping my `subscribe` code in a `tick` just makes it run twice with the same data.

https://dev.to/isaachagoel/svelte-reactivity-gotchas-solutions-if-you-re-using-svelte-in-production-you-should-read-this-3oj3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the compiled output you can see that the reactive statements are triggered on `update`, which should only happen once per event loop.

```js
    $$self.$$.update = () => {
        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$containers*/ 256) {
            $: console.log(`$: There are ${$containers.length} containers`);
        }

        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$items*/ 128) {
            $: console.log(`$: There are ${$items.length} items`);
        }

        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$denormalizedContainers*/ 64) {
            $: console.log(`$: There are ${$denormalizedContainers.length} denormalized containers`);
        }
    };
```

You can create your own method of bundling updates in an event loop. E.g. using [micro tasks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide):

```js
function debouncedSubscribe(store, callback) {
    let key;
    return store.subscribe(value => {
        key = {};
        const currentKey = key;
        queueMicrotask(() => {
            if (key == currentKey)
                callback(value);
        });
    });
}

debouncedSubscribe(denormalizedContainers, value =>
    console.log(
        `Subscribe: There are ${value.length} denormalized containers`
    )
);
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/31b237cbf100495ea180d498dd769dd5?version=3.48.0)

There is no way to cancel micro tasks again, so the old ones are invalidated via a key. Other ways of ensuring that only the last task is executed might be more elegant.

With `setTimeout` this can be done as well, and with that the previous one can be cancelled, but the minimum delay will be larger:

```js
function debouncedSubscribe(store, callback) {
    let timeout;
    return store.subscribe(value => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => callback(value));
    });
}
```